# Fritzing file for prototyping shield

Tags: arduino-uno

I have a prototyping shield with mini breadboard similar to [Adafruit Proto Shield for Arduino Kit - Stackable Version R3](http://www.adafruit.com/products/2077).

Is there a Fritzing file for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick google search turned up a solution in the very first result:

https://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=36560

It is a contribution from an Adafruit customer. 
All credits go to them.

Source thread: https://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=36560